# Build failed - Unable to resolve dependency for ... Could not resolve project

Tags: android

I'm using android studio version `3.2.1`. I have take following repo as a clone and import that project to AS.

[LAYER Android-XDK-Messenger Github](https://github.com/layerhq/Android-XDK-Messenger)

When building the project Android Studio shows following error messages.

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could 
not resolve project :xdk-ui.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for 
':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project 
:xdk-ui.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for 
':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :xdk- 
ui.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': 
Could not resolve project :xdk-ui.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for 
':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project 
:xdk-ui.
Open File
Show Details
```

gradle file
 [image]

build.gradle

[image]

I have check online status of Android Studio android its connected to internet.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: try using classpath gradle version 3.1.4

Comment: i have changed classpath gradle version to 3.1.4. but still same error message coming.

Comment: then try using runnerversion except alpha1 with any updated version

Comment: Can you explain little bit

Comment: the runnerversion and rulesversion that is 1.0.2-alpha1 in the screenshot u shared, i am not sure but the alpha1 versions of libraries cause errors usually. try using 1.1.0, clean it, remove build folders cache clean as well

Comment: I have changed that to non alpha version. but still issue comes.

Comment: I have pasted my answer below. please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have incomplete project, The project you are trying to use has xdk-ui sdk (named Android-XDK @ 22ea7b0) as a module in it, you have to download from here https://github.com/layerhq/Android-XDK/tree/22ea7b0bc0f944522dfeb1b3c07f049d9c9bef2b and paste it then import it and then compile it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is,

first option is,
Invalidate cache/Restart then in your Project level build.gradle file make changes as below,

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
           url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
           url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

change your repositories as above.

**OR** 
Second option is,
you may have disable the internet connection. so, to enable it,
Go to File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Uncheck offline work.

I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: Changed files according to your answer.but still same issue is coming.